# VSCode extension test runner for jest

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-extensions

When using the [official generator](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/yocode) to start a VSCode extension, it automatically generates the `extension.test.ts` and `index.ts` files. [`index.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-generator-code/blob/master/generators/app/templates/ext-command-ts/src/test/index.ts) just contains the setup for the test runner to use for extension tests, and it is Mocha based. The Mocha test runner itself can be seen here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-vscode/blob/master/lib/testrunner.js.

I've been scouring around trying to find any official Jest based one. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Did you find something or build it yourself?

Comment: I found this project that had working code:  https://github.com/rozzzly/vscode-prompt-debug/tree/master/test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official one, you have to create it yourself.

Igor Soloydenko wrote a guide on how to do that last year (2019):

https://medium.com/@soloydenko/end-to-end-testing-vs-code-extensions-via-jest-828e5edfeb75

Psuedocode:

```
const jestTestRunnerForVSCodeE2E: ITestRunner = {
  run(testsRoot: string, clb: (error: Error, failures?: number) => void): void {
    try {
      const result = runJestTests(configuration);
      if (result.executionError) {
        clb(result.executionError);
      } else {
        clb(undefined, result.numberOfFailedTests);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      clb(e);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = jestTestRunnerForVSCodeE2E;
```

And of course there is the link @user1795832 provided: https://github.com/rozzzly/vscode-prompt-debug/tree/master/test

The code in that link was last updated May 2018 so not sure if it still works.